# Twilio - Play audio file stored on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, twilio, voip, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm trying to play an audio file using the `<Play>` verb, but Twilio is making a POST request to retrieve it instead of a GET, and S3 doesn't accept it.

The file is [this one](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ricochet-ringtones/ringtones/us-ring.mp3)

And here's the request and the response on Twilio's console.[image]

Any ideas on how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it should be doing a POST to get the audio file. Could you paste some of your code in where you are making the request and your TwiML

Comment: lol yeah you're right .. that was the conference waitUrl, I fixed it with the waitMethod. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, the issue was on the conference `waitUrl`, which I fixed by specifying the `waitMethod`.